# Waitforsingleobject for event doesn't work

Tags: delphi, winapi, synchronization

Main thread:

(Yes, I do stop main thread right now, I really need it right now for tests, this is test unit. I will do all this stuff in another thread during final stage.)

Code:

```
function TFreHolder.GetVersion: TFreHolderVersion;
Var
 Data   : TBArray;
 StrLen : Integer;
begin
 SetLength(Data, 0);

 FFrePro.SendCommand(PROTO_COMVERSION, Data);

 ResetEvent(FAsyncMutex);

 if (WaitForSingleObject(FAsyncMutex, PROTO_COMMANDTIMEOUT) = WAIT_TIMEOUT) Then
  Begin
   ShowMessage('Timeout');
   ResetEvent(FAsyncMutex);
   Exit;
  End;

Result.DType    := BytesToWord(FActivePackage.User.Parameters, 0);
Result.DVersion := BytesToWord(FActivePackage.User.Parameters, 2);
StrLen          := BytesToByte(FActivePackage.User.Parameters, 4);

if StrLen < 32
  then Result.DDesc    := BytesToString(FActivePackage.User.Parameters, 5)
  else Result.DDesc    := BytesToString(FActivePackage.User.Parameters, 4);
```

In the COM-port watching thread:

```
procedure TFreHolder.CommandSwitcher(Package: TFreProPackage);
...
Begin
     FActivePackage := Package;
     SetEvent(FAsyncMutex)
End;
...
```

I always see timeout message, but if I comment Waitforsingleobject I can see that bytes and packages are coming.

I have created Event in Constructor this way:

```
FAsyncMutex  := CreateEvent(Nil, True, False, 'FRE_EVENT');
```

What is my mistake? I need to wait the call of CommandSwitcher function before grabbing the results.

Thanks.

Comment: No, `WaitForSingleObject` works. It is your code that does not work.

Comment: If I were you I would consider calling my event somwhat else like FAsyncEvent since calling a non-mutex object FAsyncMutex could be confusing.

Comment: @mg30rg, okay, that's left from earlier version, will change it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, can you please, show me the code that will work?

Comment: Well, I can show you code that uses CreateEvent, waits for it to be signaled, signals it, and thus releases the wait. But will that really help you? The problem is in your code and we cannot see enough of it. An SSCCE would help us.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Okay, I will try to describe the situation, hope it will help more.

I have the device which works by COM-port. Usually I can ask it for a value and it will answer. But sometimes it can send me a signal without any request. So I made async realization of the protocol, so when the watching thread grabs enough bytes to construct a package it calls callback function CommandSwitcher. It's very useful when I receive unexpected signal from the device. But I also need to handle with usual blocking request-answer commands. So I need to send command, wait for answer and show it.

Comment: How about that SSCCE? Otherwise my best guess is that the wait is timing out before `CommandSwitcher` is called. Is your timeout too short? Why do we have to guess? Wouldn't it be better for everyone if you showed an SSCCE?

Comment: Have you tried to replace PROTO_COMMANDTIMEOUT to INFINTE and see if  captures the inputs? Can you show the context of the GetVersion method's caller

Answer (score 6):

Well the code

```
ResetEvent(FAsyncMutex);
if (WaitForSingleObject(FAsyncMutex,...
```

is definitely a mistake because it ignores the async nature of threads.

Comment: It would probably be helpful to go one step further and explain why, perhaps also suggesting to reset the event *before* calling `FFrePro.SendCommand'.

Comment: @J... - I don't want to guess how to fix the code without seeing it all. I guess there are a lot more bugs in the whole code.

Comment: Hence the 'perhaps'.  Nevertheless, it is unquestionably the case that resetting an event *after* having started the signaling thread and *before* calling `WaitForSingleObject` creates a race condition where the thread in question has opportunity to set the event before the waiting thread resets it.  Telling OP he doesn't understand what he is doing is not an answer, IMO.  That much is obvious - it's why he's asking the question.  The answer should at least offer *some* explanation.

Comment: I thought the `CommandSwitcher` method is called from a different thread context (which could signal the event without leading to a wait timeout). @J... the question is *"what is my mistake ?"* and this post most probably answers that.

Comment: There are 2 extreme opinions about the poor questions - to downvote them or to try to answer more than can reasonably be answered. I think both opinions are wrong.

Comment: Nobody wants you to answer more than possible. Just to explain why the code you highlight is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that another thread is receiving the response and then signaling `FAsyncMutex` when it has been received, then you need to call `ResetEvent()` before calling `SendCommand()`, not after.  If the thread happens to receive the response before the sender is able to call `ResetEvent()` then it is forcing `WaitForSingleObject()` to timeout by clearing the condition it is waiting for.

Also, if `WaitForSingleObject()` times out waiting for an event to be signaled, do not call `ResetEvent()` since the event is not singaled.

Try this:

```
var
  Ret: DWORD;
...
ResetEvent(FAsyncMutex);
FFrePro.SendCommand(PROTO_COMVERSION, Data);

Ret := WaitForSingleObject(FAsyncMutex, PROTO_COMMANDTIMEOUT);
if Ret <> WAIT_OBJECT_0 then
begin
  if Ret = WAIT_TIMEOUT then
    ShowMessage('Timeout')
  else
    ShowMessage('Error');
  Exit;
end;
```